# Print out the contents of the component in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I need to print out the contents of the particular component in React.

Example like: Component renders some text with a button, If I click the button it should print out the content. I'm new to react can anyone help me over here.

I gone through this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print but not working in right way, because it prints the whole page, How can I customize this functioality ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please explain in detail what you've tried so far and what is "not working in right way"?

Comment: Hi BreakBB, I have used the react-to-print plugin but it printing all the pages as itis, but how can we customize the print function.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Like what component are you trying to print, what result do you get and what do you expect?